# postgres create table with clause

Tags: postgresql

I has been faced with a situation I should dynamically get the columns (along with column types) to create a foreign table.

```
 CREATE FOREIGN TABLE ossexample
 (id varchar(64), b varchar(64), c varchar(64), d varchar(64), e bigint)
      SERVER somserver 
      OPTIONS
 ( dir'osstest/',delimiter ',' ,
     format 'csv', encoding 'utf8');
```

But there's a situation that other engineer wants to add column to it, and I want to build this foreign table dynamically.

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length                                                          
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = '<tablename>';
```

the outcome is like:

```
 column_name |     data_type     | character_maximum_length
-------------+-------------------+--------------------------
 id          | character varying |                       64
 b           | character varying |                       64
 c           | character varying |                      255
 d           | integer           |
 e           | bigint            |
```

More detailly:

1.It's 9.4 postgres.. which mean I can't use inherit...

2.I googled about with clause, but I can't figure how to do it with multiple lines. I think I should get table column info from this query.